# Use Python to change to normal mode

Tags: insert-mode, normal-mode

I'm writing a function that uses Vim's Python API. The function runs while I'm in `insert` mode and I want this function to set my mode to `normal` mode.

I tried a few things, like for example, this

```
import vim
vim.eval(r'execute normal! \<esc>')
```

But unfortunately this doesn't work. I just get the error `VIM:E121: Undefined variable: execute`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, generally speaking, I'd really like to know more about the `vim` module. It doesn't have a `__file__` attribute, assuming that's because it's compiled. Is there source code anywhere I can view? Or generally where the file lives so that I can try importing it and running `help(vim)` without having to re-run my functions in a Vim environment. If you have any information on that, in particular, it'd help a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is more of a vim issue than a python one.  `vim.eval` is basically the same as vim's `eval(` which evaluates an *expression* and does not run a *command* like `execute`.  Additionally, your syntax for `execute` is wrong since the command takes a string: `execute "normal! \<esc>"` would be more correct.  You could instead use the expression form `execute()`:

```
vim.eval(r'execute("normal! \<esc>")')
```

However, since you ultimately want to use a command I would recommend just using `vim.command(cmd)` instead.  vim already has a command for leaving insert mode, `stopinsert`.

```
 vim.command('stopinsert')
```

The documentation for the methods in the built-in `vim` module can be found using `:help python` which brings up `doc/if_pyth.txt`.

Comment: I see a have a lot to learn. Thanks for your help. For some reason neither command works in the context that I need it in (the UltiSnips plugin) but I did a quick test using vimscript which calls Python and it works.